# Searching for the proper linq to sql query

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, code-first

I am creating a simple application in Visual Studio 11 with C#, for a Library.

In simple words it interacts with a database (SQL Server) to register a new book in the database.

The user is prompted to enter the book name, author, language, year, publisher of the book, and book ID.All of these are columns in a table called `BookInformation`. There is another table which is called `Categories`. For now this table doesn't matter at all, because the functionality for this table is not yet implemented.

We are talking always for books, not for magazines (for example).

I want to ask you how to make the proper query to display in one line all the information for each book stored in the database.

What I did so far is :

```
var allBooks = from p in db.BookInformation
               where p.CategoryId == "BOOKS"
               orderby p.BookName
               select p;

        Console.WriteLine("All books in database:");
        foreach (var item in allBooks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", item.BookName, item.Author, item.Year, item.Language, item.BookId);
        }
```

It gives very strange results, and its clear that it is wrong.What should I do, any ideas?

Thank you

**Edit - This is the sql it produces**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[BookId] AS [BookId], 
    [Extent1].[BookName] AS [BookName], 
    [Extent1].[Author] AS [Author], 
    [Extent1].[Publisher] AS [Publisher], 
    [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
    [Extent1].[Language] AS [Language], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent1].[TimeOfRegistrating] AS [TimeOfRegistrating] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[BookInfoes] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE 
    N'BOOKS' = [Extent1].[CategoryId] 
ORDER BY 
    [Extent1].[BookName] ASC
```

Comment: Can you post what the results are? It's not specific enough information to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Load up an instance of [Sql Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx), start profiling, run your C# LINQ code, and capture the sql it generates.

Then, determine why the sql it generates doesn't produce the correct results. That linq query is about as simple as they come. Maybe your data isn't what you are expecting it to be.

Here are other options for those of you without profiler...
http://www.thereforesystems.com/view-query-generate-by-linq-to-sql/

**Update**

Based on your sql, and your loop and writeline, you should be seeing approximately the same thing out of your console as the following sql, which is identical to your sql, except for the removal of the fields that you are not outputting to the console:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[BookName] AS [BookName], 
    [Extent1].[Author] AS [Author], 
    [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
    [Extent1].[Language] AS [Language], 
    [Extent1].[BookId] AS [BookId]
FROM 
    [dbo].[BookInfoes] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE 
    N'BOOKS' = [Extent1].[CategoryId] 
ORDER BY 
    [Extent1].[BookName] ASC
```

If you are not, then we are missing some information as to why, because everything you've said so far points to the two having roughly the same output.

Another note, `allBooks.Count()` should return the same number as the number of rows returned from your sql.

Comment: The output of what, the sql when you execute it? Or your linq query? The point I was making is that your problem isn't well defined, I was trying to help you track down where it might be.

Comment: The generated sql query seems fine to me:

SELECT  
[Extent1].[BookId] AS [BookId], 
[Extent1].[BookName] AS [BookName],  
[Extent1].[Author] AS [Author],  
[Extent1].[Publisher] AS [Publisher],  
[Extent1].[Year] AS [Year],  
[Extent1].[Language] AS [Language],  
[Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId],  
[Extent1].[TimeOfRegistrating] AS [TimeOfRegistrating] 
FROM [dbo].[BookInfoes] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'BOOKS' = [Extent1].[CategoryId] 
ORDER BY [Extent1].[BookName] ASC

Comment: But the output in the console is looking like:<br/> 
-,"someauthor",<br/> 
-, sielaSoft, <br/> 
-1991, , <br/> 
..<br/> 
It seems that it queries the database for each item in it, it gives a new line for each item (author, bookname, year..) and on each line on the console it writes only one item.I suspect that you cannot understand what I mean, but it is strange for me, and very hard to explain, so I am sorry :S.

Comment: Just to explain, this is one of my first attempts to use sql :)

Comment: It queries the database once, producing that sql code, which returns a set of data back to your console app. Then your console app loops through the data, and for each row in the set, it outputs a few of the fields using Console.WriteLine. It calls Console.WriteLine once for each row in the set that is returned. That is expected. The sql is executed as soon as you start iterating over your allBooks variable, and is only executed once.

Comment: Have you got any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Fix what? It looks like it is behaving the way it is written. What are you trying to make it do that it is not doing.

Comment: All i want is to display the information for each book in one line per book.For Example:
Book Name: .NET, Author: J. S. Turner, Year: 2003...

Comment: the output in the console is something like:
-".Net", , , , <br />
-,"J.S. Turner", , , , <br />
-, , "2003", , ,<br />
and so on.It fills only one item from the columns on each line and a lot of commas.
I want the output to be something like all the information for each book on one line.Not all the elements on separate lines.The mistake is in the foreach loop I think.It displays one line per ellement, and fills it only with the value of the current element for example:
"- , , , 2003, ," .

Comment: How can i modify the foreach loop so it will loop the rows in the table, and will display all the elements of the current row?I am really stuck here, i dont have any idea how to do it since i tried several ways , and non of them worked fine..